# Unity error: 'the name "x" does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I've got the error

> The name `direction` does not exist in the current context".

My code is the following:

```
void OnMouseDrag()
{
    
    Vector3 mousePosition = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);

    Vector2 desiredPosition = mousePosition;
    
    float distance = Vector2.Distance(desiredPosition, startPosition);
    if ( distance > maxDragDistance)
        Vector2 direction = desiredPosition - startPosition;
        direction.Normalize();
        desiredPosition = startPosition + (direction * maxDragDistance);
    if ( desiredPosition.x > startPosition.x)
        desiredPosition.x = startPosition.x;

    rigidbody2D.position = desiredPosition;
}
```

I think it is something to do with line 53

```
Vector2 direction = desiredPosition - startPosition;
```

Comment: This is a typo. [Use curly braces](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/37763.c-if-else-statement-curly-braces-or-not-an-in-depth-analysis.aspx) `{ }` with your if statements. Without them, you're only scoping the first line. Indentation doesn't matter.

Answer (score 1):

Your error is not use of brackets { }

As follow:

```
if ( distance > maxDragDistance)
        Vector2 direction = desiredPosition - startPosition;
        direction.Normalize();
        desiredPosition = startPosition + (direction * maxDragDistance);
```

In your code Vector2 direction.... is executed only the if condition is true but the next line direction.Normalized() is always executed

Please fix your code as follow:

```
if ( distance > maxDragDistance) {
        Vector2 direction = desiredPosition - startPosition;
        direction.Normalize();
        desiredPosition = startPosition + (direction * maxDragDistance);
}
```

Comment: Thank you it now works fine, I am following a tutorial and thought it was weird that there where not any curly braces as you need them in c++ ( which I have done a littlie of). but thanks again.